Trouble with Drag-and-Drop on Mobile Devices in React (with react-konva)
I'm encountering an issue where drag-and-drop functionality implemented with  elements within a react-konva canvas in a React application works perfectly on desktop browsers but fails on mobile devices. Despite setting the draggable attribute on the  elements, dragging doesn't initiate on touch events.
I have a React application that includes components for displaying icons ( elements) within a grid (IconsGrid) and on a canvas (react-konva). These icons should be draggable using the HTML5 drag-and-drop feature facilitated by react-konva. While this works flawlessly on desktop browsers, it doesn't respond to touch events on mobile devices.
import React from 'react';
import './Icon.scss';

const Icon = ({ name, ...props }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                  <img
                    draggable="true"
                    {...props}
                />
            </div>
            <p>{name}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Icon;

import Icon from './Icon';

const IconsGrid = ({ dragImage }) => {
    const icons = [
        // Icon data objects
    ];

    return (
        <div className="IconsGrid">
            {icons.map(({ name, src }) => (
                <Icon
                        key={name}
                        name={name}
                        alt={name}
                        src={src}
                        onDragStart={(e) => {
                            dragImage.current = e.target;
                        }}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default IconsGrid;


import IconsGrid from './IconsGrid';
import '../../styles/components/MyComponent.scss';

const MyComponent = () => {
    const dragImage = React.useRef();

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <IconsGrid dragImage={dragImage} />
                </div>
        <div
    onDrop={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        stageRef.current.setPointersPositions(e);
        addImage({
            ...stageRef.current.getPointerPosition(),
            src: dragImage.current.src,
            width: dragImage.current.clientWidth,
            height: dragImage.current.clientHeight,
        });
    }}
    onDragOver={(e) => {
      
        e.preventDefault();
    }}
>
    {/* Render the canvas stage */}
    <Stage
        width={1081}
        height={608}
        ref={stageRef}
    >
        <Layer>
            <Rect width={1079} height={608} fill="black" />

            {images.map((image, index) => (
                <URLImage
                    key={`image-${index}`}
                    image={image}
                    offsetX={image ? image.width / 2 : 0}
                    offsetY={image ? image.height / 2 : 0}
                    isSelected={`${image.x}${image.y}` === selectedImg}
                    onSelect={() => {
                        selectImg(`${image.x}${image.y}`);
                    }}
                    onChange={(newAttrs) => {
                        // Update image attributes on change
                        const updatedImages = [...images];
                        updatedImages[index] = newAttrs;
                        setImages(updatedImages);
                    }}
                />
            ))}
        </Layer>
    </Stage>


</div>

            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;


Additional Notes:
The drag-and-drop functionality works as expected on desktop browsers (using mouse events) within a react-konva canvas.
The issue arises specifically on mobile devices where touch events (onTouchStart, onTouchMove, onTouchEnd) do not trigger the drag-and-drop behavior.
I've verified that the draggable attribute is correctly applied to the  elements within the Icon component and that the react-konva canvas is properly set up.
